# Etag usage for subsequent request

Tags: office365

Response data in Office365 is in ODATA enveloped JSON format. We have @odata.etag property in response, which is an opaque string value that can be used in a subsequent request to determine if the value of the entity has changed.

I am using GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages API. I received etag property as part of response. 
I tried using this property as a part of If-None-Match and ETag headers for the next GET request.
But I am still getting response code as 200, which in ideal case for etag should be 304.

Please let me know if there is any way of using etag property received as part of response?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also could reproduce this issue. No matter the value specified for the If-None-Match, the update REST executed successfully. However the If-Match works well.

If you want the Office 365 REST to support the If-None-Match, you may submit the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com).